# How to prepared statement in WebSql with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sqlite, web-sql

How do I change this MySql prepared statement into WebSql query statement

```
"SELECT a.id,a.title, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('{"id":',b.id,', "name":"',b. `name`,'", "number":"',b.number,'"}') ORDER BY b.name), ']')AS people FROM contact_group AS a LEFT JOIN contact_list AS b ON a.id = b.gID GROUP BY a.id, a.title"
```

This is my complete query

```
function fetchContactGroup(){
db.transaction (function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("SELECT a.catID, a.title, ||('[', GROUP_CONCAT( ||('{""id"":',b.id,', ""name"":"',b. name,'", ""number"":"',b.number,'"}') ORDER BY b.name), ']')AS people FROM CONTACTGROUP AS a LEFT JOIN ALERTCONTACT AS b ON a.catID = b.catID", [], function (tx, results) {                 
                var len = results.rows.length;
                var output_results = [];
                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                   output_results[i] = results.rows.item(i);
                }
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        $scope.cGft = output_results; 
                    })
        },function(tx, error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                 })
    })
}
```

I have done everything I could but it is still giving me error.

I will be glad if anyone can help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` in `SQLite` doesn't allow `ORDER BY`, and concatenation is done with `||`, not the `CONCAT` function.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I have done the changes you suggested, however I am still getting syntax error. I think it has to do with the way the quotes '" are wrapped around the code and arguments. I wil be glad if you can help me with that.

Comment: It would be best if you posted the actual Javascript code, so we can see how all the quoting is done.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks, I have update the question with the query.

Comment: @DavidAddoteye: The `||` operator in SQLite is used to combine strings, e.g. `SELECT 'foo' || '-bar'` will produce the string `'foo-bar'`. Please revise your code accordingly. Additionally, do not build JSON this way - select individual columns, turn them into an array of objects and use `JSON.stringify` on that array.